# convert image to byte array

Tags: php

i want convert image into byte array in php.actually i am accessing web service in dot net.where i want to pass image as byte array.i tried this code

```
  $data1 = file_get_contents("upload/1311677409gen1.jpg");
  $byteArr1 = str_split($data1);
  foreach ($byteArr1 as $key=>$val) 
   { 
    $byteArr1[$key] = ord($val); 
   }
```

and send this array name to web service.but i got error parameter is not valid.i googled it.but dont get proper solution.i need it urgent.help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A byte array is a very specific data type that does not exist in PHP. How is .NET talking to PHP and why can't you just send the image as-is in binary form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the .net webservice, you probably have two options:

1. [Stream](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) the image
2. [base64](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) encode the image before transfer, provided the webservice can decode it.